# Is there an efficient way of looping through a cursor with parameters so the cursor doesn't have to be declare more than once?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I keep finding myself needing to output data into CSVs using PLSQL. Essentially I have a select query and for each value in the 'Supplier' column, I need a new CSV creating and populating with all data for that Supplier.

The way I've learned to go about this is by having a cursor to return only the Supplier, then feeding this in as an argument to the Supplier Data cursor, which selects the data. Using this method, I can create a spreadsheet for each supplier in the Supplier loop and populate the spreadsheet data in the Supplier Data loop for each supplier.

The problem with my method is that I need two separate cursor declarations to return essentially 1 select query's worth of information; one to select the supplier and one to select the data for each supplier. This could be particularly troublesome if the cursor is complex and requires a lot of time to return any results as I would potentially be double handling the work.

Is there a more efficient method for this, so I only need to open a select query once, thereby reducing processing time?

```
--Create table
CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER_DATA AS
        (SELECT 'SUPPLIERA' SUPPLIER,1 data1,2 data2
        FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'SUPPLIERB',3,4
        FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'SUPPLIERC',5,6
        FROM DUAL
        )

;

/

declare 

    CURSOR c_SUPPLIER_ID is
        (SELECT SUPPLIER
        FROM SUPPLIER_DATA
        );

    CURSOR c_SUPPLIER_DATA (SUPP_ID VARCHAR2) IS
        (SELECT data1, data2
        FROM SUPPLIER_DATA
        where SUPPLIER = supp_id
        );    


begin

    for r_SUPPLIER_ID in c_SUPPLIER_ID loop

        /* create file for supplier here */

        for r_SUPPLIER_DATA in c_SUPPLIER_DATA (r_SUPPLIER_ID.SUPPLIER) loop

            /* populate supplier data here */
            NULL;

        end loop;    

    end loop;    

end;
```

Comment: It would certainly help if you would edit your opening post to provide relevent CREATE TABLE statements, and some INSERT statements to populate those tables with sample data .. say two rows in the supplier table and a couple of rows for each supplier, in the "supplier data" table.  However, just off-hand, instead of declaring your cursors, it looks to me like a nested CURSOR .. FOR loop would be the easiest way. Even for simple situations, I never formally declare a cursor; instead I always use some for of a cursor for loop.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an efficient way of looping through a cursor with parameters
>   so the cursor doesn't have to be declare more than once?

There are many ways of approaching one problem. You already idenitified one however, i am going to show 2 more ways.

> 1) Removing the `CURSOR` to overcome the overhead of declaring a
>   `Cursor`
>
> 2) Bulk Operation to overcome the looping itself

- **Approach 1:**

  ```
  --Create table
      CREATE TABLE supplier_data
        AS
          ( SELECT 'SUPPLIERA' supplier,
                   1 data1,
                   2 data2
            FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'SUPPLIERB',
                 3,
                 4 FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'SUPPLIERC',
                 5,
                 6 FROM dual
          );
  ```

  Block

  ```
  declare
   -- Overhead of declaring a Cursor is omitted
  /*
   CURSOR c_supplier_id is 
    ( SELECT supplier 
      FROM supplier_data
    );

    CURSOR c_supplier_data ( supp_id VARCHAR2) 
     IS ( SELECT data1,
                  data2
           FROM supplier_data
           where supplier = supp_id
    );
    */

  begin

    for r_supplier_id in ( SELECT supplier 
                           FROM supplier_data
                          ) 
     loop
          /* create file for supplier here */
         for r_supplier_data in ( SELECT data1,
                                        data2
                                  FROM supplier_data
                                  where supplier = r_supplier_id.supplier)
            loop
              /* populate supplier data here */
        NULL;
      end loop;
    end loop;
  end;
  ```
- Approch 2:

  ```
       -- Table to insert data        
         Create table Tst_tab(col1 number,col2 number);

        --Create table
          CREATE TABLE supplier_data
            AS
              ( SELECT 'SUPPLIERA' supplier,
                       1 data1,
                       2 data2
                FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'SUPPLIERB',
                     3,
                     4 FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'SUPPLIERC',
                     5,
                     6 FROM dual
              );
          /
        --Type to hold intermediate result

          Create or replace type supp_id is table of varchar2(100);
  ```

Block

```
declare
  v_supp_id     supp_id := supp_id ();
  -- record to hold intermediate result
  type supp_data is record ( col1          number,
                             col2          number );
  -- Variable of type table to hold result
  type v_supp_data is    table of supp_data;
  -- Variable of type of table
  var           v_supp_data := v_supp_data();

  l_err_count   number;      
  bulk_errors exception;
begin
  -- Selecting all Suppliers at one go
  SELECT supplier
  BULK COLLECT INTO
    v_supp_id
  FROM supplier_data;

  -- Selecting Results on Supplier id
  SELECT data1,
         data2 
  BULK COLLECT INTO var
  FROM supplier_data
  where supplier MEMBER OF v_supp_id;

  -- Populating the target table. You can Delete or Update as well
  BEGIN
    FORALL i in 1..var.count save exceptions
      insert into tst_tab values var(i);

  exception
    when bulk_errors then
      l_err_count   := sql%bulk_exceptions.count;
      dbms_output.put_line('Error Count = ' || l_err_count);
  END;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Running a query to loop through rows inside another query looping through rows is sure way to slow code. There are many ways you can avoid running the second query.

Assuming that each supplier could have many data rows, one way around this is to:

- Group the data by supplier
- Loading the detail into nested object tables
- This gives you one cursor, for each row of which you loop through the nested table

To do this, first create some object types:

```
create or replace type supplier_data_t as object (
  data1 int,
  data2 int
);
/

create or replace type supplier_data_arr
  is table of supplier_data_t;
/
```

And you're good to go:

```
select supplier, 
       cast ( 
         collect (
           supplier_data_t ( data1, data2 )
         ) as supplier_data_arr
       ) data
from   supplier_data
group  by supplier;

SUPPLIER     DATA                        
suppliera    CHRIS.SUPPLIER_DATA_ARR([CHRIS.SUPPLIER_DATA_T])  
supplierb    CHRIS.SUPPLIER_DATA_ARR([CHRIS.SUPPLIER_DATA_T])
supplierc    CHRIS.SUPPLIER_DATA_ARR([CHRIS.SUPPLIER_DATA_T], [CHRIS.SUPPLIER_DATA_T])

begin
  for sdata in (
    select supplier, 
           cast ( 
             collect (
               supplier_data_t ( data1, data2 )
             ) as supplier_data_arr
           ) data
    from   supplier_data
    group  by supplier
  ) loop
    dbms_output.put_line ( sdata.supplier );
    for d in 1 .. sdata.data.count loop
      dbms_output.put_line ( sdata.data(d).data1 );
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/

suppliera
1
supplierb
3
supplierc
5
7
```

You could also aggregate the supplier data information to JSON, XML, ...

Answer (score 0):

Example of nested CURSOR FOR loop:

```
for s in (select supplier_id,
                 supplier_name
                 from suppliers
         )
loop
   -- code to open csv file with name of s.supplier_name
   for d in (select col_a,
                    col_b
             from supplier_data
             where supplier_id = s.supplier_id
            )
    loop
       -- code to write to csv file
    end loop
end loop
```

Comment: Is there any benefit of looping around a select like this rather than a cursor (aside from readability and the option to dynamically select data)?

Comment: It _is_ a cursor.  Just not an explicit declared one.  As for benefits ... what more benefits do you want?

Comment: None, I was just checking that i'm not missing anything. I've updated the original question now to hopefully assist in illustrating my issue.